# How to replace string in all documents in Mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to replace a string in certain documents. I have googled this code, but it unfortunately does not change anything. I am not sure about the syntax on the line bellow:

```
pulpdb = db.getSisterDB("pulp_database");
var cursor = pulpdb.repos.find();
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
  var x = cursor.next();
  x['source']['url'].replace('aaa', 'bbb'); // is this correct?
  db.foo.update({_id : x._id}, x);
}
```

I would like to add some debug prints to see what the value is, but I have no experience with MongoDB Shell. I just need to replace this:

```
{ "source": { "url": "http://aaa/xxx/yyy" } }
```

with

```
{ "source": { "url": "http://bbb/xxx/yyy" } }
```

Comment: The Mongo shell runs arbitrary javascript which suggests that youre code works. Have you simply tried it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It doesn't correct generally: if you have string `http://aaa/xxx/aaa` (`yyy` equals to `aaa`) you'll end up with `http://bbb/xxx/bbb`.
But if you ok with this, code will work.

To add debug info use `print` function:

```
var cursor = db.test.find();
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
  var x = cursor.next();
  print("Before: "+x['source']['url']);
  x['source']['url'] = x['source']['url'].replace('aaa', 'bbb');
  print("After: "+x['source']['url']);
  db.test.update({_id : x._id}, x);
}
```

*(And by the way, if you want to print out objects, there is also `printjson` function)*

Comment: Oh I did not try "print" :-) That simple! Okay, I can see the data are coming in, I guess I have a snag in the regexp (the real case is not xxx but https://abc.blablab.com)

Comment: Got it - I had to do x['source']['url'] = x['source']['url'].replace(...) instead.

Comment: Hmm for some strange reason the variable is replaced but the data is not stored then. Do I need to perform a commit or something? I still see old data there.

Comment: @Izap Have you changed db name in the last line?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. Is there a way to do this between two different collections? @om-nom-nom

Comment: nice answer.. worked perfect.. can I know what language is this syntac.. is this specific to mongoshell?

Comment: @Sravan it's javascript in mongoshell :-) mongo does some exports for you, and usual javascripts becames valid

Comment: i try this code but i see Updated 0 record(s) after every update call.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this if you are on MongoDB 2.6 or newer is looping over the cursor object using the [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method and update each document usin ["bulk"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk) operations for maximum efficiency.

```
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;

db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    print("Before: "+doc.source.url);
    bulk.find({ '_id': doc._id }).update({
        '$set': { 'source.url': doc.source.url.replace('aaa', 'bbb') }
    })
    count++;
    if(count % 200 === 0) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }

// Clean up queues
if (count > 0) 
    bulk.execute();
```

---

From [MongoDB 3.2](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2/#mongo-shell-and-crud-api) the [Bulk()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk) API and its associated [methods](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2-reference/#db.collection.bulkWrite) are deprecated you will need to use the [`db.collection.bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2-reference/#db.collection.bulkWrite) method.

You will need loop over the cursor, build your query dynamically and [`$push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) each operation to an array.

```
var operations = [];
db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    print("Before: "+doc.source.url);
    var operation = {
        updateOne: { 
            filter: { '_id': doc._id }, 
            update: { 
                '$set': { 'source.url': doc.source.url.replace('aaa', 'bbb') }
            }
        }
    };
    operations.push(operation);
})
operations.push({ 
    ordered: true, 
    writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 5000 } 
})

db.collection.bulkWrite(operations);
```

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays,

- starting `Mongo 4.2`, [`db.collection.updateMany`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html) (alias of `db.collection.update`) can accept an aggregation pipeline, finally allowing the update of a field based on its own value.
- starting `Mongo 4.4`, the new aggregation operator [`$replaceOne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceOne/#exp._S_replaceOne) makes it very easy to replace part of a string.

```js
// { "source" : { "url" : "http://aaa/xxx/yyy" } }
// { "source" : { "url" : "http://eee/xxx/yyy" } }
db.collection.updateMany(
  { "source.url": { $regex: /aaa/ } },
  [{
    $set: { "source.url": {
      $replaceOne: { input: "$source.url", find: "aaa", replacement: "bbb" }
    }}
  }]
)
// { "source" : { "url" : "http://bbb/xxx/yyy" } }
// { "source" : { "url" : "http://eee/xxx/yyy" } }
```

- The first part (`{ "source.url": { $regex: /aaa/ } }`) is the match query, filtering which documents to update (the ones containing `"aaa"`)
- The second part (`$set: { "source.url": {...`) is the update aggregation pipeline (note the squared brackets signifying the use of an aggregation pipeline):

  - [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#pipe._S_set) is a new aggregation operator (`Mongo 4.2`) which in this case replaces the value of a field.
  - The new value is computed with the new [`$replaceOne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceOne/#exp._S_replaceOne) operator. Note how `source.url` is modified directly based on the its own value (`$source.url`).

Note that this is fully handled server side which won't allow you to perform the debug printing part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB can do string search/replace via mapreduce. Yes, you need to have a very special data structure for it -- you can't have anything in the top keys but you need to store everything  under a subdocument under `value`. Like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("549dafb0a0d0ca4ed723e37f"),
    "value" : {
            "title" : "Top 'access denied' errors",
            "parent" : "system.admin_reports",
            "p" : "\u0001\u001a%"
    }
}
```

Once you have this neatly set up you can do:

```
$map = new \MongoCode("function () {
  this.value['p'] = this.value['p'].replace('$from', '$to');
  emit(this._id, this.value);
}");
$collection = $this->mongoCollection();
// This won't be called.
$reduce = new \MongoCode("function () { }");
$collection_name = $collection->getName();
$collection->db->command([
  'mapreduce' => $collection_name,
  'map' => $map,
  'reduce' => $reduce,
  'out' => ['merge' => $collection_name],
  'query' => $query,
  'sort' => ['_id' => 1],
]);
```

Comment: This isn't a correct approach to the problem - mapReduce can produce a new result set, it should not be used to "replace" existing values this way.  Plus you are depending on something extremely specific - formatting your collection this way just to output _id,value pairs seems way more complicated than the already given answer to do it by iterating over documents in the shell.

Comment: Not all web applications have privileges to execute shell commands. Another approach would be to retrieve all into PHP, replace and save back but in server surely is faster. Finally, could you quote some official documentation as why it shouldn't be used this way? I haven't read anything saying you shouldn't merge into the source.

Comment: you are neither mapping nor reducing :)  Basically, you are overwriting and that's not really the purpose of "mapReduce" - you are literally doing an update of each document.  At best, this can be described as a hack (that only works on this exact specific format of the document)

Comment: Yes. this is a hack. Of course it is. And yet. It's a useful hack.