# Search and replace a string in an array in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have the following data structure in Mongo which I want to edit:

```
{
   "images" : [{
      "image_id" : 46456,
      "image_path" : "http://cdn.site.com/image.jpg",
      "image_thumbnail" : "http://cdn.site.com/image.jpg",
      "image_detailed" : "http://cdn.site.com/image.jpg",
      "image_type" : "0"
    }, {
      "image_id" : 46452,
      "image_path" : "http://cdn.site.com/image.jpg",
      "image_thumbnail" : "http://cdn.site.com/image.jpg",
      "image_detailed" : "http://cdn.site.com/image.jpg",
      "image_type" : "2"
    }, {
      "image_id" : 46453,
      "image_path" : "http://cdn.site.com/image.jpg",
      "image_thumbnail" : "http://cdn.site.com/image.jpg",
      "image_detailed" : "http://cdn.site.com/image.jpg",
      "image_type" : "0"
    }, {
      "image_id" : 46454,
      "image_path" : "http://cdn.site.com/image.jpg",
      "image_thumbnail" : "http://cdn.site.com/image.jpg",
      "image_detailed" : "http://cdn.site.com/image.jpg",
      "image_type" : "A"
    }]
}
```

I would like to replace all the 'http' in the entire array to 'https' regardless which field they are in.

How do I do so ?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace string in all documents in Mongo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042450/how-to-replace-string-in-all-documents-in-mongo)

Answer (score 7):

There is no built-in functionality in MongoDB. You can replace all the http with https by looping all records. In the Mongo shell you can do it as follows :

```
String.prototype.replaceAll=function(s1, s2) {return this.split(s1).join(s2)}

var cursor = db.myCollection.find({},{_id:0});
while(cursor.hasNext()) {
    var obj = cursor.next();
    var objStr = JSON.stringify(obj);
    var newObjStr = objStr.replaceAll("http","https");
    db.myCollection.update(obj,JSON.parse(newObjStr));
}
```

Comment: Unless the data was always simple, I'd not use the exact way you've got it. I'd minimally want to add colons to search and replace to prevent `https` from becoming `httpss`. I'd probably also make sure it was at the start of the value in case it was embedded as a query string param.

Comment: I always get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`. db is my mongoose connection `db = mongoose.connection` where I can perform queries via my models. And I changed myCollection with the name of my collection.